# Nested Parallel While Loops

Tags: multithreading, matlab, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, matlab-guide

I am trying to run two while loops in parallel for the purpose of data acquisition.
This program will run for "n" `num_trials` with specific trial duration for each trial.

During each trial, the program will collect data while keeping track of the trial duration. For example, the first trial starts collecting data at 1 seconds and stops at 10 seconds. This process will repeat for the rest number of trials

How can I run both while loops in parallel?

Basically, I just want a method that will break the second while loop once the specified trial duration is complete?

Thanks in advance.

```
count = 0;
num_trials = 5; % Number of Trials = 5 Trials
trial_duration = 10; % Trial Duration = 10 Seconds

global check 
check = 0;

% Number of Trials
for i = 1:num_trials

    fprintf('Starting Trial %i\n', i);

    t_start = tic;

    % Start counting and Collecting Data
    while toc(t_start) < trial_duration

        % Data Collection
        while (check ~= 1)  
            count = count +1;
        end

    end

    fprintf('Ending Trial %i\n', i);
end
```

Comment: Which two while loops are you referring to? I think you need to rethink how you are storing your data.

Comment: @jdero There are only while loops in the code. The first one is a timer and the second is data collection. I am not concern about storing the data at moment.

Comment: have you had a look at parallel toolbox?

Comment: @Marcin I have tried parfor loop but that will not work for this application. I am looking at SPMD but I am not sure if they compute independently on there seperate worker nodes. I need the first while loop to stop the second while loop after then seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using a single loop with `&&` ?

```
while (toc(t_start) < trial_duration) && (check ~= 1)

        % Data Collection
        count = count +1;

end
```